# Ensuring UITableViewCell is laid out before requesting images

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, autolayout

I have a `UITableView` showing a list of text and associated images within custom `UITableViewCells`, using Autolayout to lay out the contents of the cells. The exact layout of the cells will vary depending on device screen size and orientation.

The images are fetched over a network, with request parameters providing the width and height required. These parameters are obtained from `cell.mainImageView.bounds`.

The problem I have is that when the `UITableViewCells` are first loaded, the contained `UIImageView` has not yet been laid out and has placeholder bounds values from the Storyboard. Which means images are not requested at the correct resolution.

**I can make the problem go away by calling `cell.layoutIfNeeded()` before accessing the image view bounds in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. But I wondered if there was a better solution?**